Can I test my pinia store and intercept URLs with cypress without visiting the GUI?
I want to test my pinia store actions results - right error throwing, and other behavior with cypress.
therefor I want to intercept my api endpoints.
As a result of my interception I get a html result, which I cannot find in any other case:
api call result: (punchline not my expected fixture but a error script from cypress)
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>integration/undefined/api/resource1/1/resource2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.domain = **'localhost'**;
      
      (function(parent) {
        var Cypress = window.Cypress = parent.Cypress;
        if (!Cypress) {
          throw new Error("Tests cannot run without a reference to Cypress!");
        }
        return Cypress.onSpecWindow(window, [{"absolute":"/***/tests/e2e/support/index.js","relative":"tests/e2e/support/index.js","relativeUrl":"/__cypress/tests?p=tests/e2e/support/index.js"},{"absolute":"tests/e2e/specs/undefined/api/resource1/1/resource2","relative":"tests/e2e/specs/undefined/api/resource1/1/resource2","relativeUrl":"/__cypress/tests?p=tests/e2e/specs/undefined/api/resource1/1/resource2"}]);
      })(window.opener || window.parent);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

My expectation is that this line has the most information, but I don't find anything to that integratoion/undefined part.
<title>integration/undefined/api/resource1/1/resource2</title>
this is my test file:
You can see I don't call cy.visit("/") (is that a problem?)
import { createPinia, setActivePinia } from 'pinia'
import {useRes2Store} from "@/store/resources/res2Store";

describe('Res2 Store', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        const pinia = createPinia()
        setActivePinia(pinia)

        
        cy.fixture('res.json').as('res2')
        cy.intercept('GET', '/api/resource1/1/resource2', {fixture: 'res.json'})
    })

    it('Call the tagStore action to get res2 items to a res1', () => {
        const res2Store = useRes2Store()  // Store initialisieren

        cy.wrap(res2Store.getRes2(1)).then(() => {
            cy.get('@res2').then((res2) => {
                expect(res2Store.res).to.deep.equal(res2)
            })
        })
    })
})


I tried to find config parameters. Do I need to set any .env.test file up?
I checked that the fixture is working
I saw, that in the console of the cypress test, the get request is sent
sadly to: http://localhost:8080/__cypress/iframes/integration/undefined/api/resource1/1/resource2
port 8080 is the vuejs app itself:
App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 

my cypress config:
{
  "pluginsFile": "tests/e2e/plugins/index.js"
}


FWIW this a misuse of Cypress, I'm not sure it's possible with it at all. Use Jest/Vitest for this kind of tests

I thought so :D @EstusFlask but I really like the way the intercept works

There's nothing wrong with not loading a page if you're not going to test any DOM. But did you leave out the punch-line? Are you saying the intercept is not catching the call?

Yes it is catching it, but returns not my fixture

Figured out it is actually not catching, due to an old and maybe buggy cypress version. Updated to latest, moved to component test, added an actual component @EstusFlask and now it is working.

It may be better to wait on the intercept rather than asserting directly after the action call.
I didn't have a problem with your test code, but it may depend on the amount of processing occurring post-fetch (in the action).
There is a sample Pina app lmiller1990/pinia-example which I downloaded and updated to latest Vue/Pinia.
It has a products store with a fetchAll() action that fetches from window.fetch('http://localhost:8080/products'). I modified the fetch to match yours: window.fetch('/api/resource1/1/resource2').
Modified test
import { createPinia, setActivePinia } from 'pinia'
import { useProductStore } from '../../src/store/products'

describe('Products Store', () => {
  beforeEach(function() {
    const pinia = createPinia()
    setActivePinia(pinia)

    cy.fixture('products.json').as('products')
    cy.intercept('/api/resource1/1/resource2', {fixture: 'products.json'})
      .as('pinia')
  })

  it('Call the productStore.fetchAll() action', () => {
    
    const productsStore = useProductStore() 
    cy.then(() => productsStore.fetchAll())

    cy.wait('@pinia').then(() => {
      cy.get('@products').then(products => {
        const all = productsStore.all
        expect(all['1']).to.deep.eq(products[0])
        expect(all['2']).to.deep.eq(products[1])
      })
    })
  })
})

products.json fixture
[
  {"id":"1", "name":"cypress"},
  {"id":"2", "name":"pinia"}
]

Cypress log


Thanks for the answer. I tried your approach, and now I am running in a Timeout on the pinia waiting. I tried it with the full url and with only the path ... both run into timeout. Telling me:  No request ever occurred.
my store returns a promis on the getRes2() method ... is that a problem?

The timeout means your intercept is not catching, so adding cy.wait('@pinia') actually gives you useful information (since you previously thought the intercept was catching, but now know that it's not).

I substituted your URL /api/resource1/1/resource2 into both cy.intercept() and the Pinia action, and it still works for me (i.e. it's not a problem with the URL format).

There are indications in the question from http://localhost:8080/__cypress/iframes/integration/... and "pluginsFile": "tests/e2e/plugins/index.js" that you are using quite an old version of Cypress. This might be the problem as cy.intercept() has received quite a few bug fixes over the years.

If you still have problems, post a link to a repo for the app and I'll sort out a working test for you.

It was about the Version and about the waiting ... thanks @Aladin Spaz for the idea to check the version
